# CSS Allow absolute element to expand to be wider than parent

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu on my site's top navigation bar. I'd like the items in this menu to expand horizontally to fit their contents. For some reason they won't expand to be wider than their parent.

I've recreated the issue in CodePen here: http://codepen.io/YM_Industries/pen/GgJBQv

In my actual website I don't have control over this section of the DOM, so I'm a little constrained there.

Here's the code for my recreation in case CodePen is unavailable:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">v&nbsp;&nbsp;Test1&nbsp;&nbsp;v</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="http://example.com">Submenu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://example.com">Long text wraps and is ugly :/ </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">Test2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul.nav,
ul.nav li,
ul.nav ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

/* Style each link */
ul.nav li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(254, 197, 46, 1);
  border: none;
}

/* Bring back the first level links */
ul.nav > li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

/* Selected/Hover effect */
ul.nav li > a:hover {
  color: #004d85;
  background: rgb(255, 213, 102);
}

/* Display dropdown in the correct location */
ul.nav li ul.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  display: none;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}

/* Set font+colour for site links */
ul.nav li a, 
ul.nav li a:link, 
ul.nav li a:visited {
  color: black;
  font-size: medium;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav li a:hover,
ul.nav li a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

If I explicitly set a width on my submenu items (400px for example) they will expand correctly, but for some reason the content isn't making them get wider. I'd really rather not have to hardcode the width.

Thanks,

YM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is rather easy. You just have to add

```
ul.submenu a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

which prevents the text from wrapping and therefore doesn't stick to the parent container size.

You can check it out here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwbYvG

Comment: Try adding an example as a snippet or pen.  You'll get more up votes.

Comment: That *was* easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Godisgood Roger that. Added a pen. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

just fixed your pen - upgrade your css classes:

```
ul.nav li ul.submenu 
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  width:auto;
  display: none;
  background: rgb(254, 197, 4);
}

ul.nav li ul.submenu > li
{
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image]

### AND IT USES CSS 2 :)